# Pattern Package Installation is failed

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I'm Using pattern package to do some NLP Tasks, i tried to install the package to work out on ***Google Colab*** by ::

**!pip install pattern**

but i have got this error ::

### ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

while installing the dependancies specifically "mysqlclient" package and then raises "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pattern'"

i have read many many articles that i should install first "setup.py" but still can't relate any good answer.
please any Help!